# What is the proper term for one of the disjuncts in a query using UNION?

Tags: sql, union, terminology

Complete the sentence: In the query

```
SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1;
```

the sub-selects `SELECT 0` and `SELECT 1` are properly known as the ___________s of the `UNION`.

I am not looking for *your opinion* on what would be a good name - I want you to back your answer up with a reference to some kind of authoritative source.

Comment: Standard SQL calls them `<query expression body>`

Comment: dnoeth, why not add a link to a source for that and post it as an answer

Comment: As you can see from the answers there doesn't seem to exist a commonly used name for the parts. I don't know any either. As the parts are queries, Oracle's idea to call them "component queries" (Mureinik's answer) seems appropriate. Rather than naming the two subqueries, we'd more likely refer to their results, though. So, Jon's suggestion to talk about "result sets", is good, but not the perfect answer to the question on how the *sub-selects* are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the Standard SQL document correctly this seems to be called `<query term>`.

It's hard to find SQL:20xx online, Itzik Ben-Gan shows the relevant part in [Fundamentals of table expressions](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/04/t-sql-queries/table-expressions-part-1)

```
7.17 <query expression>
 

Function
Specify a table.
 

Format
  <query expression> ::=
    [ <with clause> ] <query expression body>
      [ <order by clause> ] [ <result offset clause> ] [ <fetch first clause> ]
  <with clause> ::=
    WITH [ RECURSIVE ] <with list>
  <with list> ::=
    <with list element> [ { <comma> <with list element> }… ]
  <with list element> ::=
    <query name> [ <left paren> <with column list> <right paren> ]
      AS <table subquery> [ <search or cycle clause> ]
  <with column list> ::=
    <column name list>
  <query expression body> ::=
      <query term>
    | <query expression body> UNION [ ALL | DISTINCT ]
        [ <corresponding spec> ] <query term>
    | <query expression body> EXCEPT [ ALL | DISTINCT ]
        [ <corresponding spec> ] <query term>
  <query term> ::=
      <query primary>
    | <query term> INTERSECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ]
        [ <corresponding spec> ] <query primary>
  <query primary> ::=
      <simple table>
    | <left paren> <query expression body>
        [ <order by clause> ] [ <result offset clause> ] [ <fetch first clause> ]
        <right paren>
  <simple table> ::=
      <query specification>
    | <table value constructor>
    | <explicit table>
  <explicit table> ::=
    TABLE <table or query name>
  <corresponding spec> ::=
    CORRESPONDING [ BY <left paren> <corresponding column list> <right paren> ]
  <corresponding column list> ::=
    <column name list>
  <order by clause> ::=
    ORDER BY <sort specification list>
  <result offset clause> ::=
    OFFSET <offset row count> { ROW | ROWS }
  <fetch first clause> ::=
    FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } [ <fetch first quantity> ] { ROW | ROWS } { ONLY | WITH TIES }
  <fetch first quantity> ::=
      <fetch first row count>
    | <fetch first percentage>
  <offset row count> ::=
    <simple value specification>
  <fetch first row count> ::=
    <simple value specification>
  <fetch first percentage> ::=
    <simple value specification> PERCENT
```

Comment: It seems like in your quoted definition, "query expression body" is the term being used for the whole expression, i.e. "SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1". "query term" is the term for one of the individual selects.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the "result sets".

> A UNION concatenates result sets from two queries. But a UNION does
> not create individual rows from columns gathered from two tables.

From here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) refers to them as "component queries".